# How do you update a DynamoDB column with values from a pandas DataFrame using a ID as a common value

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table called returns-portal in dynamoDB, I also have a DataFrame with two columns order_name and return_status.

I need to update dynamoDB table, return_status column with the values in my DF (df2) using the order_name as the ID against both data sets, and an order_name can appear multiple times in the DynamoDB table but only once in the df2. The problem I am having is I really don't understand how this is possible. I've tried to put something together myself but it won't work, see below code:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
import json
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from func.excelfunction import *
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import requests
import csv
import os
import math
from sql_server.sql_server import *

#Connect to ETL DB

df1 = run_sql_df('SET NOCOUNT ON; select distinct order_number, return_status from etl_db.dbo.shopify_returns_portal')
df1 = df1.astype({"order_number":"str","return_status":"str"})

filename = 'test_file.csv'

df1.to_csv(str(filename),index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv')
df2 = df2.astype({"order_number":"str","return_status":"str"})


#create update statement for DynamoDB

def update_status(order_number,return_status, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb",aws_access_key_id ="XXXXXXXXXXXX",aws_secret_access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",region_name = "eu-west-1")

    table = dynamodb.Table('returns-portal')

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'order_number': df2.order_number
        },
        UpdateExpression="set return_status =:r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': df2.return_status
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':

    update_response = update_status(df2.order_number,df2.return_status)
    print("Update movie succeeded:")
    pprint(update_response, sort_dicts=False)
```

the error i am getting is:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>" for value "0        25061198
1        25061184
2        14441634
3        14441639
4        25061205
5     26054929503
6        25061203
7        25061186
8        14441629
9        25061187
10       25061201
11       25061196
12       14441636
13       25061177
14       25061194
15       14441641
16       25061189
17       25061206
18       25061204
19       14441628
20       25061199
21       25061185
22       14441633
23       25061197
24       25061180
25       14441638
26       25061192
27       25061195
28       14441637
29       25061193
30       25061200
31       14441635
Name: order_number, dtype: object"
```

I have a strong suspicion that I am doing this completely wrong but I cannot find anything online in regards to people using a dataFrame to update a DynamoDB table. From looking at it I feel as though you might have to iterate over rows in dynamoDB but i have no clue on if that is the case, or how to do it.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Convert it to list of dictionaries using the to_dict method in pandas. Then iterate over that list and call update on every dictionary item.

Answer (score 0):

You're not iterating through the list of the order_number or return_status, you're sending the whole column (or series).

First though, not sure why you are re-reading the csv to df2, just use df1 throughout - it's the same data...

To get lists to iterate through, you can use zip or to_dict as mentioned. Here's a zip example. It gives a list of tuples.

```
onum_status_pair_list = list(zip(df1['order_number'], df1['return_status']))
```

then you want to iterate over this. Updating your code:

```
def update_status(order_number,return_status, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb",aws_access_key_id ="XXXXXXXXXXXX",aws_secret_access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",region_name = "eu-west-1")

    table = dynamodb.Table('returns-portal')

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'order_number': order_number
        },
        UpdateExpression="set return_status =:r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': return_status
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # note use of parenthesis to iterate list of tuples
    for (onum, stat) in onum_status_pair_list:
        update_response = update_status(onum,stat)
        print("Update movie succeeded:")
        pprint(update_response, sort_dicts=False)
```

If you run into issues, shoot me a note. Don't have a way to test this...